# Merge records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to modify the data structure in mongodb, but I don't know a good way.

Current data:

```
{"user_id": 123, "prod_id": 123},
{"user_id": 123, "prod_id": 234},
{"user_id": 123, "prod_id": 345},
...
```

And I want to create the data below from above one:

```
{"user_id": 123, "prod_id": [123, 234, 345]},
...
```

I know I should use relational db, though I have to use mongodb for some reason.

Comment: check mongo aggregation `$group` and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to save data in new structure in mongodb. You can store in new collection or replace the same collection. for same collection keep backup first then test.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
 {
  $group:
      {
       _id:"$user_id",
       prod_id: { $addToSet: "$prod_id" }
      }
  },
  { $out : "newCollectionName" }

])
```

**N.B:** If you just want to send your expected format data as a response but don't want to change data structure then don't need `$out` stage.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: '$user_id',
           'prod_id': { $push: '$prod_id' }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.sales.aggregate([
 {
   $group:
      {
       _id:"$user_id",
       prod_id: { $addToSet: "$prod_id" }
      }
  }

])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
           {
                 $group:{
                     _id:"$user_id",
                     prod_id: { $push: "$prod_id" }
                     }   
            } 

])
```

Comment: Please explain why this answers the question